# If $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous with $\int f =1$, then $f(a)f(b)=1$ for some $a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

If I am given a function $$ f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ which is continuous, and for which $ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 1$ , how do I prove the existence of $a,b\in (0,1)$ with $a<b$ such that $f(a)f(b)=1$? Also, how could I prove that there are infinitely many such pairs?

I have tried various things, such as working with the integral and trying to find some form of it to which I could apply MVT for definite integrals on an interval $[0,1/2]$, so that I could get an '$a$' in said interval and $b=1-a$, though I've had no success yet. I'm thinking the solution wouldn't even use said theorem, as the values HAVE to be inside $[0,1]$ and NOT $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877331/the-use-of-integrals-in-demonstrations

Comment: Hint: Prove that either $f=1$ or there exist $a,b\in (0,1)$ such that $f(a)<1<f(b)$. Then use continuity to get your points.

Comment: What does the image of $f$ (that is, the range of values it takes on) look like?

Comment: @sudeep5221 didn't notice, my bad 

Comment: @BrianTung it is only specified that it takes values in R(real numbers set)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven alright, ill give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: RemWheel, have fun :)

Comment: @RemWheel: It's a hint. ;-) There is more that you can say about the *image* or *range* of $f$ (as opposed to its *codomain*, the reals) than simply that they are all real values. Could the image be, for example, $\{0.5, 1.5\}$? (I.e., not the interval between $0.5$ and $1.5$, but just those two specific values.) Could the image be the interval $[0, 0.75)$? And so forth.

Comment: @BrianTung well, continuity would obviously imply that it cannot be the first example, as for the other though it very well could be. Thus, I'm guessing I'll have to play around with it's image for a bit then :) EDIT: whoops, big mistake, if it's max would be <1, it would also imply the definite integral given is smaller than 1, which is not the case.

Comment: @RemWheel: Yes, now you're thinking the right way!

Comment: @BrianTung wait, so now i have f(a)<1<f(b), which means the function takes the value 1 in at least 1 point, though now i would have to prove it is not unique, since that would contradict what im supposed to prove, right?

Comment: I could imagine the proof in my head, though maybe not in a formal manner: were i to have such function, around the point it takes the value 1, there would have to exist a really small interval on which f would take two values of the form: f(x1)=a and f(x2)=1/a, for a really close to 1. A graph would be of great help here 

Answer (score 0):

One has to look at the function $g(x,y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$ and integrate it over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Clearly, we get that this integral is $1$ so the rest follows from a middle value theorem.

Comment: I am unsure what this has to do with the question at hand. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Presumable "middle value theorem" refers to the mean value theorem. If $D = [0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $\int_D g(x,y) dxdy$, then for some $(a,b) \in D$ we have $g(a,b) = \int_D g(x,y) dxdy/\int_D dxdy = 1$. Thus, $f(a)f(b)=1$. We may assume, WLOG, that $a \leq b$. However, I don't think it's guaranteed that $a < b$.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout Thanks for the explanation. Indeed, I don't think we get $a<b$.